# Keep rows with list overlaps in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df with two indexes ("id" and "cluster"). There is "team" column which is a list. Like the below df:

```
id          cluster          team
1             5            [CS, VS]
              6              [CS]
2             3            [CS, CS]
              1              [VS]
              2              [TD]
3             8          [CS, CS, VS]
              9              [TD]
```

I'd like to look at each "id" and see if its "team" rows have an overlap or not. For example, in the first id, [CS, VS] and [CS] have overlap, sharing "CS". If there is no overlap, that "id" and its rows are dropped. So, the output should look like this:

```
id          cluster          team
1             5            [CS, VS]
              6              [CS]
```

"id" 2 and 3 are dropped because there are no overlap between [CS, CS], [VS], [TD] or [CS, CS, VS] ,[TD].

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```py
# Let's show how the data is built
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'cluster': [5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 8, 9],
    'team': [["CS", "VS"], ["CS"], ["CS", "CS"], ["VS"], ["TD"], ["CS", "CS", "VS"], ["TD"]]
}).set_index(['id', 'cluster'])

# Find which indices in the DataFrame meet the criteria
overlap_idx = (
    df.explode("team")  # Dealing with list columns is awful, let's make them individual rows
      .reset_index()  # Need to reset index for the drop_duplicates call
      .drop_duplicates()  # We don't want to count duplicate values in the same cluster as an overlap
      .groupby(["id", "team"])  # Now we're checking if multiple clusters have the same team within each id
      .filter(lambda x: any(x.count() > 1))  # Count the number of clusters with same id and team, keep if > 1
      .set_index(["id", "cluster"])  # Put the index back
).index  # Only keep the final, filtered index

df.loc[overlap_idx]  # Select overlap indices from original data
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, and your help. I tested your code, and I get 
"AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'"
I think your code is correct, and I do not have the right version of the library. I wrote a code that does the job, but it is not efficient. I will check your solution as correct. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, and it correctly does the job. But, it is not very efficient. I still appreciate any more efficient solution :)

```
for rows in set(df.index.get_level_values(0)):

     all_items = list(df.loc[rows]['team'])
     unique_items_in_each_row = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([set(i) 
                                 for i in all_items]))
     unique_items_all_rows = set(unique_items_in_each_row)
     if len(unique_items_in_each_row) == len(unique_items_all_rows):
          df.drop([rows], inplace=True)
```